# Flex: Converting DateField text to seconds?

Tags: apache-flex

Is there anything wrong with following snippet of code?

```
var d:Date = DateField.dateToString(myDateField.text,"DD/MM/YYYY");
        testTextArea.text = d.getSeconds().toString();
```

> Error: Implicit coercion of a value of
>   type String to an unrelated type Date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:  DateField.dateToString's first parameter is supposed to be a date.  It then takes that date and returns a string using the second parameter as a format string.

It looks like you're trying to convert the string to a date (the other way around) so you can get the seconds from it and put it in the text area.  The DateField control has a selectedDate parameter that will give you the date you need.  Then you just run this code to put it in the text area:

```
testTextArea.text = myDateField.selectedDate.getSeconds().toString();
```

Comment: It should work but in testTextArea I am getting a zero only. Don't know why.

Comment: What do you get if you do this:

testTextArea.text =  DateField.dateToString(myDateField.selectedDate,"DD/MM/YYYY");